# Duplicate key error when trying to write an $group aggregation to mongodb from Spark using scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, aggregation-framework

**Edit: This edit may change the course of this issue.**

A mongodb aggregation (specifically with $group) run on spark is creating duplicate _id records when writing back to the collection. As a result, mongodb is throwing duplicate key error. BTW, this query runs perfectly fine in mongo shell.

Here is what I did:

I took a small data set and I printed the results of (aggregation) spark code to the console instead of writing into the collection. I printed the complete result set and I found duplicates in _id field. The data looks something like this: (edited)

```
Document{{_id=Document{{prodCategory=123},{proId=ABC},{‌​location=US}}, details=[Document{{....}},Document{{....}},Document{{...}}, count=2223}}

Document{{_id=Document{{prodCategory=123},{proId=ABC},{locat‌​ion=US}}, details=[Document{{....}},Document{{....}},Document{{...}}, count=123}}.
```

There are many such repeated documents. what I don't understand is, why is spark not consolidating the complete (map ??) job before writing it to the collection? each partition is just mapping the records and writing it to the collection directly. That's is not how it is supposed to work right?

If there is any advise from experts on how to resolve this issue or you see anything that should be changed in my code from **original post** below. Please advise.

**original Post:**

I have the following collection.

```
prodTransactions:
{
_id:
ProdCategory:
product:
location:
customer:
eventTime:
status:
}
```

My aggregation lists all customers and dates for a {ProdCategory-Product-location} group where status is 'complete'. The following is the mongodb code.

```
db.prodTransactions.aggregate([
{$match: {status:'complete'}
, {$project: 
    {
        prodId:1,
        location:1,
        customer:1,
        status:1,
        eventTime:1,
        prodCategory:1
    }}
, {$group: 
    {
        _id: {prodCategory: "$prodCategory", lab: "$prodId", location: "$location"},
        details: {$addToSet: {customer: "$customer", date: {$dateToString: {format: "%m/%d/%Y", date: "$eventTime"}}, time: {$dateToString: {format: "%H:%M:%S", date: "$eventTime"}}}},
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
, {$out : "prodAgg"}
],{allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

When I run this in mongodb directly, it runs perfectly, no issues and saves all the data to prodAgg collection. The aggregated collection looks like this (data edited):

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "prodCategory" : "category1",
        "prodId" : "prod1",
        "location" : "US-EAST"
    },
    "details" : [ 
        {
            "customer" : "xxx@yyy.com",
            "date" : "07/15/2016",
            "time" : "14:00:48"
        }, 
        {
            "customer" : "aaa@bbb.com",
            "date" : "07/15/2016",
            "time" : "19:05:48"
        }, 
        {
            "customer" : "ccc@ddd.com",
            "date" : "07/15/2016",
            "time" : "17:55:48"
        }, 
        {
            "customer" : "eee@fff.com",
            "date" : "07/15/2016",
            "time" : "19:20:49"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 4.0
}
```

The issue is, If i execute this from spark trying to write it to a collection. It writes a few documents and then fails with the following exception (data edited):

> com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on
>   server 192.168.56.1:27017.  Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=6,
>   code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   dbname.prodAgg index: *id* dup key: { : { prodCategory: "xxx", prodId:
>   "yyyyy", location: "US-EAST" } }', details={ }}].     at
>   com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:176)

This error has been haunting me for the past 3 days and i'm not able to get past this.

my understanding is (I may be wrong but), group aggregation in itself should not have any duplicates, then how/why is it throwing duplicate key error. Or am 'I doing something wrong in my aggregation? or scala code?

If any soul out there has seen this before, please shed some light and pull me out of this whirlpool. I would really be grateful

Here is my scala code. I'm using the

> mongodb-spark-connector

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.mongodb.spark._
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.spark.config._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ProdAnalytics1").setMaster("local").
      set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://192.168.56.1:27017/dbname.prodTransactions")
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.56.1:27017/dbname.prodAgg")

      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val rdd = sc.loadFromMongoDB()

      val aggRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(
      Document.parse("{$match:{status:'end'}"),
      Document.parse("{$project: {prodId:1,location:1,customer:1,type:1,eventTime:1,prodCategory:1}}"),
      Document.parse("{$group: {_id: {prodCategory: \"$prodCategory\", prodId: \"$prodId\", location: \"$location\"},details: {$addToSet: {customer: \"$customer\", date: \"$eventTime\"}},count: {$sum: 1}}}"),
      Document.parse("{$sort: {count : -1}}, {allowDiskUse: true}")))
    println(aggRdd.count)

// Using the write Config to Write to DB
     val writeConf = WriteConfig(sc)
     val writeConfig = WriteConfig(Map("collection" -> "prodAgg", "db" -> "dbname"), Some(writeConf))
     MongoSpark.save(aggRdd, writeConfig)
```

My SBT file:

```
name := "Simple Project"
    version := "1.0"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"

    //libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.1"

    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1"

    libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "1.1.0"

    libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.2.1"

    resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
    resolvers += "snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ "
    resolvers += "releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

Note: Reason for not using the latest version of spark is, in latest version it is throwing another exception:

> Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

For the life of me I could not understand what this is and I'm not even using dataframes. so...I'll leave it at that..if someone has any advise on this, I will gladly take it.

Any advise is greatly appreciated...Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is the mongo log while scala code is running. This is the last piece before it failed (**edited**)

> command dbname.ProdTransaction command: aggregate { aggregate:
>   "ProdTransaction", pipeline:  [ { $match: { _id: { $gte:
>   ObjectId('554c949ae4b0d28d51194caf'), $lt:
>   ObjectId('55be257be4b0c3bd1c74e202') } } },  { $match: { $and: [ {
>   status: "end" }, { location: "US" }, { prodId: { $nin: [ "abc", "xxx",
>   "yyy" ] } } ] } },  { $project: { prodId: 1, location: 1, customer: 1,
>   status: 1, eventTime: 1, prodCategory: 1 } },  { $group: { _id: { lab:
>   "$prodId", location: "$location" }, details: { $addToSet: {
>   prodCategory: "$prodCategory", user: "$customer", date: "$eventTime" }
>   }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },  { $sort: { count: -1 } } ]  cursor: {} }
>   cursorid:258455518867 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1335
>   reslen:4092243 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2694 } },
>   Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1347 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: {
>   r: 1347 } } } protocol:op_query 1155ms

Comment: You should go back to db and check if there are any indexes and delete indexes for `prodAgg` collection and start over.

Comment: @SagarReddy: This is a new collection that is created at run time. So this does not exist before this execution.

Comment: I think your problem is not with the data that you are inserting. Looks like the database collection state is not clean. What do you get when you run `db.prodAgg.getIndexes()` on your db ?

Comment: Here is what I see (edited). Any discrepencies that you see?
`MongoDB Enterprise > db.prodAgg.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "dbname.prodAgg"
        }
]`

Comment: Try `db.prodAgg.drop()`. This should remove that index and you can try running your aggregation again. Not sure if that is problem.

Comment: ok...let me try. will update you.

Comment: Dropped the table and tried again. Same error. It created the table and index again. :-(

Comment: Can we assign the _id value from my aggregation - just a incremental integer so that the system does not assign one?

Comment: Couple of things to note here. Your shell output is different from what you've in aggregation code. I don't think system will assign any id because your grouping key will be your id for the collection. So help me understand here does the aggregation code insert any data into collection ?? You may want to strip all the code and just try basic aggregation  to see where the problem is. Get rid of group altogether and see if you can run aggregation.

Comment: @SagarReddy: I did strip out all the code, got rid of the group. Once I removed the group, it started working. But when i added back the group, then it threw the same error again. So something with the group aggregation that it is not liking. Any ideas? I will also look for other examples, but please share if you have any info.

Comment: @Vamsi I've got a very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731354/mongospark-duplicate-key-error-only-on-massive-datasets), do you have any advice?

Comment: @TheM00s3: No. I'm still hunting the solution. But I was able to use data frames to do the aggregation. The Data frames did not serve as well as group aggregation did, but I was able to move on. I will find out the resolution for this and will post it here soon. If you have a solution, please do that same.

Answer (score 1):

Theres lots to answer here, so I've broken my answer down to three sections; configuration, why it happens and how to work around it:

### Configuration issues

> Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

Happens when the wrong version of the MongoDB Spark Connector is used with Spark.  If you want to use Spark 2.0.x then you'll need the 2.0.x MongoDB Spark Connector eg:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.0.0"
```

(These misleading errors can also happen if your Scala versions aren't in sync eg using Scala 2.10 with a library that compiled for 2.11)

Regarding the installation there is no need for: `libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.2.1"`. Its a separate library with its own MongoClient, Codecs etc so will likely cause errors when used alongside the connector.

### Why you can expect duplicate _ids with $group aggregations

Spark works by partitioning data collections and then parallelising the data processing on them across Spark worker nodes.

There are various partitioners in the Mongo Spark Connector and all of them default the partitioning of a collection on the `_id` key of the Document. The aggregations are then performed on each of the partitions.

So as you are running multiple aggregations each on a partition of the collection, you could reasonably expect duplicate _id's produced in the resulting RDD.

### Fixing duplicate _ids

I can think of three possible fixes for the issue:

A) Given the nature of your aggregation pipeline you should use the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator. This is much more beneficial as the data stays local to MongoDB and you don't need to maintain a Spark cluster.

B) A Spark based alternative would be to do further processing on the RDD to merge any duplicated _id's before saving back to MongoDB.

C) In theory you could provide your own partitioner that returns partitions based on the grouped `_id` fields. In reality I can't think of a good way to do this without requiring partition queries that uses the `$in` filter which isn't very performant.

Comment: I'll try these and will update my answer here. Thanks for taking the time to explain in detail. Really appreciate it. BTW, I have tried "A" already and it works. This is the reason why I was so confused as to why it doesn't work in Spark. But what you said (about practitioners) makes complete sense.

Comment: Is there anyway to tell spark to use a single partitioner? I tried the following code with my conf declaration but it did not work. It is still considering the same number of partitions. `// .setExecutorEnv("spark.default.parallelism", "1").set("spark.default.parallelism", "1")`.

Comment: Here is what i did: I took a small data set and I tried printing the results of spark code to the console instead of writing into the collection. I printed the complete result set and I found duplicates in `_id field`. The data looks something like this:`Document{{_id=Document{{prodCategory=123},{proId=ABC},{location=US}}, details=[Document{{....}},Document{{....}},Document{{...}}, count=2223}}
Document{{_id=Document{{prodCategory=123},{proId=ABC},{location=US}}, details=[Document{{....}},Document{{....}},Document{{...}}, count=123}}`. This document is repeated wrt `_id`

Comment: There are many such repeated documents. what I don't understand is, why is spark not consolidating the complete map job (Reduce is what is called, right?) before writing it to the collection? each partition is just mapping the records and writing it to the collection directly. That's is not how it is supposed to work right?

Comment: A: You could use the test partitioner: `com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoSinglePartitioner`  for a single partition.  But if you aren't actually doing anything in Spark there is no reason at all to seen data to and from Spark  - it just adds latency, complexity and cost.


B: The reason for the duplicated documents has been explained. You are doing nothing with the RDD in Spark to group them, so how would Spark know you want to do that? You need to consolidate the results in Spark, if you are using multiple partitions. If you are using a single partition - why use Spark at all?

Comment: Thanks Ross. For 'B', I was thinking that the aggregation pipeline $group command is supposed to group the records by the fields I mentioned in the $group clause. But you said something about grouping the "RDD". How do we do that? Can you point me to some links where I can understand this better?

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but since your aggregate is returning an object with the key `_id`, mongo will try to use this as the ID for your document when inserting. Not sure if this is your desired result... If not, just change the `_id` key to something else (`id` even would work)

Comment: You are right. It is infact trying to add an id. Look at this from the mongo logs:
`{ $match: { _id: { $gte: ObjectId('554c949ae4b0d28d51194caf'), $lt: ObjectId('55be257be4b0c3bd1c74e202') }` plus my aggragate query is what mongo is trying to execute. Also....

Comment: I did try the solution you mentioned. Like this: `{$group: 
 {
  _id: null,
  prod: {prodCategory: "$prodCategory", prod: "$prodId", location: "$location"},
  details: {$addToSet: {customer: "$customer", date: "$eventTime"}},
  count: {$sum: 1}
 }} `
 I tried to make the _id null and change the name of the group to something else. Running that query in mongodb did not like it. It complained `unknown group operator prod`

Answer (score 0):

I have done some trail and error and narrowed down the issue (with help of Sagar Reddy's advise). Here is what I found.

The aggregation works if there is no `$group` aggregation in the code. Just `$match, $project, $sort`..any combination of commands work fine. Once I put `$group`, even with one parameter, it fails.

The reason I think it is, `$group` is the only aggregation that adds **new _id** to the collection. no other aggregation command will add a **"new"** _id. This is what the issue is and here is where the problem is.

My problem is I need `$group` for my aggregation and it would'nt help without it.

If any one of you have a solution/information on this or a workaround, please advise.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating your issue with MongoDB, here are some of my thoughts:

1. I've noticed a mistake in your aggregation query - is a lack of curly brace in "`{$match:{status:'end'}`" intentional ? It should ends up with a double brace - "`{$match:{status:'end'}}`". I changed it in my bug reproduction code.
2. IMO your aggregation query is not producing duplicated keys - once you run Spark application the prodAgg collection is created and filled with aggregation result and then if you run it second time it will produce the same keys but old collection won't be dropped first. This is a reason of your problem.

Add the following lines just before your spark aggregation:

```
val mongoClient = new MongoClient() 
val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbname")
db.getCollection("prodAgg").drop()
```

> The aggregation works if there is no $group aggregation in the code. Just $match, $project, $sort..any combination of commands work fine. Once I put $group, even with one parameter, it fails.

I couldn't reproduce that behaviour but if I add exclusion of a document's _id to the $project operator it works as your said. In that case I have an explanation - aggregation creates a new document with new _id when there is no source document's _id and then you don't have duplications. Without exclusion of _id in projection it should be inherited from source document and then duplications should occur.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. I will try your all your suggestions in a few days. Currently firefighting a different issue. Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Will update on this worked out. Thanks.